# SQL cumulative average by distinct column value (timestamp)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum, partition

I have a SQL table in the following form:

timestamp user_id Result 
1         125  1
1         125  0
2         125  1
2         144  0
3         156  1
3         125  1

etc....

If I want to find a rolling average of a users results I can use:

```
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 
AVG(result) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM table
```

If a user only had one result per timestamp, this works fine but if a user have a multiple results in a single timestamp it will average over the results on that timestamp plus timestamps before it.

So my question is how can I make sure it only averages over results which happened on when the timestamp is less than the current timestamp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need another column to break the ties, like the primary key of the table for example - otherwise peer rows are considered all together by the window average. Assuming `id`:

```
select t.*
    avg(result) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp, id) as avg_result
from mytable t
```

Note that the `rows` frame specification is not needed here (as in your original query).

If you don't have such column, then we can generate it with `row_number()`, which guarantees that each number is assigned just once. However, the result are not consistent - that is, when there are ties, the same row might be assigned a different row number during consecutive executions of the same query:

```
select t.*
    avg(result) over(partition by user_id order by timestamp, rn) as avg_result
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by timestamp) as rn
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: I agree with all this but it dosn't seem to work- it still averages over rows which have the same timestamp instead of only averaging over those with a timestamp less than the current timestamp. - I'm using Google BigQuery so maybe thats why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window frame specification.  In standard SQL, that would be:

```
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 
       AVG(result) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                         ORDER BY timestamp ASC
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1 SECOND' PRECEDING
                        ) 
FROM table;
```

EDIT:

In BigQuery, you would do:

This is standard SQL functionality, but not all databases support it.

```
SELECT user_id, timestamp, 
       AVG(result) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                         ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp) ASC
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                        ) 
FROM table;
```

This assumes that seconds are sufficient granularity for the distinguish previous times.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the reply  - unfortunately I'm suing Bigquery and it doesn;t support this

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT [timestamp]
,   [user_id]
,   [result]
,   [final_avg] = (
        CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM([result]) OVER(PARTITION BY [user_id], [timestamp] ORDER BY [timestamp], [user_id], [result] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
        / COUNT([timestamp]) OVER(PARTITION BY [user_id], [timestamp] ORDER BY [timestamp], [user_id], [result] RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING))
FROM table
ORDER BY [timestamp], [user_id], [result]
```

Result:

```
timestamp   user_id result  final_avg
1           125     0       0
1           125     1       0.5
2           125     1       1
2           144     0       0
3           125     1       1
3           156     1       1
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the reply, unfortunately this won do - the second row should ignore the first in the rolling tally since the timestamp is the same

Comment: No prob.  What is the result you're looking to achieve?  Like, what would be the expected result in `final_avg` for the first three rows in the result table above?

Comment: The final result would be: final_avg: null, null, 0.5, null, 0.66666, null. The only one with averages for the example would be 125 since for the others it is the first entry, Thanks for your help!